# How to split activity regularizer loss from mse loss term (display both)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

Say I use L1 activity regularizer on the outputs of my autoencoder. Implemented in keras using:

```
model.get_layer("pool3_encoder").activity_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01)
```

and lets say my loss function is standard mse implemented using:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule),loss='mse')
```

this will print the mse and regularizer as one total loss, how can I split this into two separate components so I can save weights whenever mse is lowest.
Is this even possible, I know the network is attempting to minimize the the sum of the two, but it would be nice to be able to tell when the mse is actually minimized.

Here is the model:

```
def Conv1DTranspose(input_tensor, filters, kernel_size,name,activation, strides=2, padding='same'):
    """
        input_tensor: tensor, with the shape (batch_size, time_steps, dims)
        filters: int, output dimension, i.e. the output tensor will have the shape of (batch_size, time_steps, filters)
        kernel_size: int, size of the convolution kernel
        strides: int, convolution step size
        padding: 'same' | 'valid'
    """
    x = Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x, axis=2))(input_tensor)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=filters, kernel_size=(kernel_size, 1), strides=(strides, 1),
                        padding=padding,name=name,activation=activation,kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(x)
    x = Lambda(lambda x: K.squeeze(x, axis=2))(x)
    
    return x


def Encoder(feats,drop):
    conv_layer_1=tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64,15,padding="same",
                                        kernel_initializer='he_uniform',
                                        name="conv1_encoder",
                                        activation='tanh')(feats)
    conv_layer_1=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(drop)(conv_layer_1)
    max_pool_1=tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(2,padding="same",
                                            name="pool1_encoder")(conv_layer_1)
    conv_layer_2=tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128,15,padding="same",
                                        kernel_initializer='he_uniform',
                                        name='conv2_encoder',
                                        activation='tanh')(max_pool_1)
    conv_layer_2=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(drop)(conv_layer_2)
    max_pool_2=tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(2,padding="same",
                                            name="pool2_encoder")(conv_layer_2) 
    conv_layer_3=tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(256,15,padding="same",
                                        kernel_initializer='he_uniform',
                                        name='conv3_encoder',
                                        activation='tanh')(max_pool_2)    
    conv_layer_3=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(drop)(conv_layer_3)
    max_pool_3=tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(2,padding="same",
                                            name="pool3_encoder")(conv_layer_3)    
    # conv_layer_4=tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(256,15,padding="same",
    #                                     kernel_initializer='he_uniform',
    #                                     name='conv4_encoder',
    #                                     activity_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01),
    #                                     activation='tanh')(max_pool_3)
    return max_pool_3

def DecoderTransposed(feats,drop):
    conv_layer_1=Conv1DTranspose(feats,256,15,padding='same',
                                                 name='Tconv1',activation='tanh')
    conv_layer_1=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(drop)(conv_layer_1)   
    # max_unpool_1=tf.keras.layers.UpSampling1D(size=2,
    #                                           name="unpool1_decode")(conv_layer_1)
    conv_layer_2=Conv1DTranspose(conv_layer_1,128,15,padding='same',
                                                 name='Tconv2',activation='tanh')
    conv_layer_2=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(drop)(conv_layer_2)   
    # max_unpool_2=tf.keras.layers.UpSampling1D(size=2,
    #                                           name="unpool2_decode")(conv_layer_2)
    conv_layer_3=Conv1DTranspose(conv_layer_2,64,15,padding='same',
                                                 name='Tconv3',activation='tanh')
    conv_layer_3=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(drop)(conv_layer_3)   
    # max_unpool_3=tf.keras.layers.UpSampling1D(size=2,
    #                                           name="unpool3_decode")(conv_layer_3)
    conv_layer_4=Conv1DTranspose(conv_layer_3,48,15,padding='same',
                                                 name='Tconv4',activation='tanh',strides=1)
    
    return conv_layer_4

def Model(ws,drop):
    input_shape=(ws,48)
    inputs=tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)  
    
    encoder_outputs=Encoder(inputs,drop)
    outputs=DecoderTransposed(encoder_outputs,drop)
    
    return tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=outputs)
```

Comment: fyi I deleted my answer because your own answer seems to be answering a question that is a lot more complicated than I thought it was. apologies.

Comment: @piterbarg no worries I kind of got the feeling there was confusion or a poor explanation on my part.